# error incorporating a select within a IFNULL in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, moodle

I'm creating a view in MariaDB and i'm having trouble making it work for a couple of fields. Currently this is working:

```
    (   SELECT  DISTINCT IFNULL(grades.`grade`,'No Grade')
            FROM  `table` grades
            WHERE  userinfo.`id` = grades.`id`
              AND  grades.`Item Name` = 'SOMEINFO'
    ) 'SOMENAME',
```

But i need to add a select where the 'No grade' is, in the following form

```
    (   SELECT  DISTINCT IFNULL( grades.`grade`, 
                SELECT  IF( EXISTS
                            (   SELECT  *
                                    FROM  `another_table`
                                    WHERE  userid = 365
                                      AND  courseid = 2
                            ), 'Enrolled', 'Not enrolled'
                          )
                               )
            FROM  `table` grades
            WHERE  userinfo.`id` = grades.`id`
              AND  grades.`Item Name` = 'SOMEINFO'
    ) 'SOMENAME',
```

i know that

```
SELECT  IF( EXISTS( SELECT  *
                    FROM  `another_table`
                    WHERE  userid = 365
                      AND  courseid = 2
                  ),
           'Enrolled', 'Not enrolled'
          )
```

is working too, but now the whole thing  it's giving me an error, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please put some effort into formulating your query.  Also, are you getting an error?  Unexpected results?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a subquery:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(grades.`grade`,
                        SELECT IF( EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                           FROM `another_table`
                                           WHERE userid = 365 AND courseid = 2
                                          ), 'Enrolled', 'Not enrolled'
                                 )
                       )
 FROM `table` grades
 WHERE userinfo.`id` = grades.`id` AND
       grades.`Item Name` = 'SOMEINFO'
) as SOMENAME,
```

You are using a subquery that returns two columns in a position where a *scalar subquery* is expected.  A scalar subquery returns one column in at most one row.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do what you want in MySQL, because of the restrictions on views.  I would advise you to rewrite the logic so the `exists` is handled using a `left join` in the `from` clause.

Comment: i was able to fix it changing the logic a little bit, it was far from elegant but it worked
a view over a view
     ifnull(`Somecolumn`,IF( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `another_table` WHERE userid = id AND courseid = 2), 'Enrolled', 'Not enrolled')) as 'Some Name',